# jQuery ajax working but axios giving CORS error

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

I am moving my project from jQuery to axios. It is working fine in other places but I am getting error in one specific place. axios is giving CORS error but jquery working fine. Here is the code:

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'my-url-here',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "attachmentNames": [ "filename.pdf" ]
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

axios

```
axios({
    url: 'my-url-here',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      "attachmentNames": [ "filename.pdf" ]
    }
  }).then(function(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
  });
```

Comment: "CORS error" — And what does that error say? There are quite a lot of different error messages related to incorrect CORS settings.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers will send a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) if you send a `Content-Type` with a value that isn't on a very short list.

`application/json` **will** trigger a preflight.

Axios will, by default, encode data as JSON and say it is sending JSON.

In your jQuery, you are *manually* encoding the data as JSON and **failing to set the correct Content-Type header**. As a result you are lying to the server and claiming the data is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (the default for jQuery). This header doesn't need a preflight request.

---

Configure the server to respond to a preflight request with permission (in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`) to change the `Content-Type`.